# How do I read data, with variable number of rows, into a set of records?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .csv file that I am reading with the csv package. The file has the following layout:

```
Date, 01/31/2021

Report id, 9172

Database: GeneralDB_v17.01.01.06

Item number: 15342
Item definition
A, Apple
R, Red, Delicious
Location, Aisle 12

Item number: 4011
Item definition
C, Carrot
O, Orange
Org, Organic
Location, Aisle 2
```

Each item is of variable length, and I would like to extract each item into a dictionary for further processing later.

```py
file_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for row in file_reader:
    if row != []:
        # identify if the given row contains a new item
        if row[0].split(':')[0] == 'Item number':
            # identify item name
            item_name = row[0].split(':')[1]
            
            # need to read entire item with its associated definition and location
            # into a dictionary so I can parse it later
```

Comment: *I have a csv file*  and the shown file format are a pure contradiction. That is not a csv file.

Comment: Interesting, the given data is an approximation of the real data I am trying to parse. However the values here are separated by commas. Maybe I have created this stand in dateset incorrectly but can you help me see how these are not values that are separated by commas?

Comment: A number of lines are also delimited by a colon. @PatrickArtner didn’t explain why it’s not CSV, but, yeah “CSV” is something very specific, and the presence of a few commas here-and-there doesn’t qualify. Click on the CSV tag, then look for “learn more” to learn what a CSV is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was discussed in the comments, your soure file is not CSV.  I see it more like a "label" where a *record* is some number of lines that has:

- a clear start (Item number)
- a clear end (first empty line after Item number)
- data in between

You need a little state machine: it's just a for-loop that reads every line and makes decisions, "this is the start of a record", "this is the end of a record", "this must be data *inside* a record".

The following state machine makes use of the `continue` statement to short-circuit the loop and the decision-making process.  This control structure allows the machine to avoid redundant logic, like "if I'm in a record ***and*** the line looks like a certain kind of data, ***then***...".

Instead, past a certain point in the for-loop, the machine knows it can only be in a record and the decisions that follow are purely about data, "this line looks like a certain kind of data and I'll act on it accordingly".

The decision making process looks like the following, ***For every line***:

1. check if line is the start of the record; set state "in record", skip to next line
2. or check if state is not "in record"; skip to next line
3. or check if line is the end of the record; unset state "in record", do something useful with the accumulated record data, skip to next line
4. or find 'Item definition' line; ignore it, skip to next line
5. finally (logically), "in record" and the line is data you care about; parse it

As you probably noticed, it has a strong bias towards skipping to the next line once it knows what kind of line it's on.  This isn't a necessary feature of a state machine, but I like it because it avoids a lot of if-statements, and especially *nesting* or *compounding* of if-statements:

```py
input_f = open('input.txt')

record = {}
for line in input_f:
    line = line.strip()

    # Test each line for the start of a record
    if line.startswith('Item number'):
        item_number = line.split(': ')[1]
        record['Item number'] = item_number
        continue

    # If not in a record, skip this line
    if record == {}:
        continue

    # Now, all tests and actions are in the context of "in record"

    # Test for end of record
    if line == '':
        print(record)
        record = {}  # unset "in record" state
        continue

    # Ignore
    if line.startswith('Item definition'):
        continue

    # Finally, parse a key/value 
    key, value = line.split(', ', 1) # (..., 1) to keep "Red, Delicious" as a single value
    record[key] = value

# Deal with last record
print(record)
```

When I run that, I get:

```py
{'Item number': '15342', 'A': 'Apple', 'R': 'Red, Delicious', 'Location': 'Aisle 12'}
{'Item number': '4011', 'C': 'Carrot', 'O': 'Orange', 'Org': 'Organic', 'Location': 'Aisle 2'}
```